# Sending HTML emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, html-email

I have a ruby application that I'd like to send HTML emails. In my mailer folder I have the appropriate html.erb files. In dev(localhost) and staging(on heroku) the html emails get sent fine, but when I try and send HTML emails in productions(hosted on AWS), I keep getting the text email, and not the html emails. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an explicit content type header:

```
mail :to => some@address.com, :subject => "your subject", :content_type => "text/html"
```

Comment: Weird, I tried that earlier and it didn't work, tried it again and this time it worked......oh the life of a coder :-/. Thanks Erez!